# Using R package BerkeleyEarth

Tags: r

I'm working for the first time with the R package [BerkeleyEarth](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BerkeleyEarth/index.html), and attempting to use its convenience functions to access the [BEST](http://berkeleyearth.org/) data. I think maybe it's just a problem with their servers (a matter I've separately addressed to the package's maintainer) but I wanted to know if it's instead something silly I'm doing.

To reproduce my fault

```
library(BerkeleyEarth)
downloadBerkeley()
```

which provides the following error message

```
trying URL 'http://download.berkeleyearth.org/downloads/TAVG/LATEST%20-%20Non-seasonal%20_%20Quality%20Controlled.zip'
Error in download.file(urls$Url[thisUrl], destfile = file.path(destDir,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://download.berkeleyearth.org/downloads/TAVG/LATEST%20-%20Non-seasonal%20_%20Quality%20Controlled.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(urls$Url[thisUrl], destfile = file.path(destDir,  :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
```

Has anyone had a better experience using this package?

Comment: I was able to download it with the following: install.packages('BerkeleyEarth'); library(BerkeleyEarth) ;  I have never used the line downloadBerkeley() and do not know what it does.

Comment: The package downloads fine--there's no problem with CRAN. downloadBerkeley() is a function within the package that accesses the BEST Data, and it's the source of the error message I posted above.

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  When I tried using downloadBerkeley() I also got an error.  Maybe we are not using downloadBerkeley() correctly.  I was able to download all of the data sets directly from their website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pointing to a different URL than one should get judging what URLs are listed at http://berkeleyearth.org/data/ that point to the zip formatted files. There are another set of `.nc` files that appear to be more recent. I would replace the entries in the `BerkeleyUrls` dataframe with the ones that match your analysis strategy:

This is the current URL that should be in position 1,1:

```
http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/downloads/TAVG/LATEST%20-%20Non-seasonal%20_%20Quality%20Controlled.zip
```

And this is the one that is in the package dataframe:

```
> BerkeleyUrls[1,1]
[1] "http://download.berkeleyearth.org/downloads/TAVG/LATEST%20-%20Non-seasonal%20_%20Quality%20Controlled.zip"
```

I suppose you could try:

```
 BerkeleyUrls[, 1] <- sub( "download\\.berkeleyearth\\.org", "berkeleyearth.lbl.gov", BerkeleyUrls[, 1])
```